# show text in a textbox in visual c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting information from an array and displaying the results in a text box on the form. The value doesn't get displayed in the UI, but it says that it has the value assigned.

```
try
{
    foreach (string r in Rows)
    {
        string[] h = new string[5];
        h = r.Split(',');
        MessageBox.Show(h[0]);
        // need to show the first record
        House newhouse = new House();

        newhouse.ID = Convert.ToInt32(h[0]);
        newhouse.Address = Convert.ToString(h[1]);
        newhouse.Type = Convert.ToChar(h[2]);
        newhouse.Cost = Convert.ToInt32(h[3]);
        newhouse.Sold = Convert.ToString(h[4]);

        loadedHouses.Add(newhouse);

        ID_Number.Text = Convert.ToString(h[0]);
        address1.Text = Convert.ToString("g");
        type1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[2]);
        cost1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[3]);
        sold1.Text = Convert.ToString(h[4]);
        MessageBox.Show("dewdwedw");
    }
}
catch (Exception qq)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", qq);
}
```

When you hover over `ID_Number` while debugging, it says the value should be 1 but it doesn't show up in the form. Can anyone help?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code, so there has to be something else that is wrong. Can you show more of the code?

Comment: What is `h` and what is the value of `h[0]`?

Comment: What happens if you change the code to ID_Number.Text = "Hello";

Comment: H is just string an array and if you change ID_Number.Text = "Hello"; nothing happens either

Comment: It would probably much more helpful and productive if you could show us more of you code.

Comment: Punctuation and spellcheck are your friends. Please check if my edits didn't lose anything important.

Comment: Does ID_Number.Text get set anywhere else? Somewhere that would cause the value to be overwritten?

Comment: 2 guesses: 1) ID_Number is not the textbox that is added to the form but another one. -or- 2) You are never leaving the debugger therefore giving the UI no chance to refresh the window at all.

Comment: This is a classic sign of using the wrong form instance.  Add this statement: this.Show();

Comment: no its not set anwhere at all

Comment: Webform, Winform, other? And I agree, more code will help..is the ID_Number TextBox nested in another control?

Comment: no the ID_Number is not nested anwhere else its just used in the Form1 tried all of them susgestions still not showing its strange how the value is not showing in the text box

Comment: Any chance the text color is set to white? I make stupid mistakes like that and it takes me forever to figure those out. Strange that the textbox says it's 1 but not displaying.

Comment: @Yatrix: Stupid Mistakes!!! We would have been best friends if met...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

One can guess whats happening here. The numbers in the textboxes will DISPLAY text from 0 to 999. Right? Wrong...the out put will be just 999 in the end of loop.

I am not an expert and i am trying to learn C#. But I know this code will work the way I am saying. Possibly you will have to do it in a separate thread. Try this...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loop));
        t.Start();
    }

    private void loop()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        }
    }
```

This code should work as you are expecting.

In the first case also textbox is getting the values continuously from the loop, but not able to display it as the Main thread is already busy. But in second case the thread is separate from the Main thread.

I am not sure it is your problem, but to me it seems so. You are assigning the text to textboxes continuously in a loop. So even though the textboxes have the values but are NOT ABLE TO DISPLAY. If you try creating a new thread, now also textboxes will have the values but will be visible in the textboxes now. Its a kind of pseudo code, just to explain my point. If you are looking for the same, its ok. otherwise throw a stone at my head.

Hope it helps.